# Qt mapToGlobal and multiple screens. How do they interact?

Tags: qt

I don't understand how mapToGlobal interacts with a multiple screen setup. Is it returning the global position relative to that particular screen, or to the whole desktop?

If I invoke QCursor.setPos(widget.mapToGlobal(widget.geometry().topLeft()) will I always end up with the pointer in the top left corner of the widget, regardless of any multiscreen situation?

Comment: Did you look at `QDesktopWidget::screenNumber(const QWidget *widget)` to get the screen number where your widget is? `QDesktopWidget::screenNumber(const QPoint &point)` could be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state for mapToGlobal: -

> Translates the widget coordinate pos to global screen coordinates

Since you're mapping from local coordinates, you can actually just use: -

```
mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));
```

Rather than having to specify the widget's top left position of the geometry.

As for mapping to Global coordinates, from memory, I think the global space is extended across the screens, so two screens at a resolution of 1024 x 768 would give a screen space of 2048 x 768, if arranged side by side.

The docs also state: -

> For desktops with multiple screens, the size of the desktop is the union of all the screen sizes

So I would expect mapToGlobal would return a value with respect to the total screen space available, rather than just the screen that the widget resides. If it didn't, it would be quite awkward to handle a widget that was placed between two screens.

Note that you can also use QDesktopWidget for information about the different screens and to check which screen a widget resides upon. It's also useful if you want to place a widget on a specific screen.

Finally, in Qt 5, there's also the QScreen class to query screen properties.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually misusing mapToGlobal. I should use the widget parent, instead of the widget. But your answer is precious to understand how it works.